# Cinnamon desktop runs only in software rendering mode on raspberry pi 4

Tags: server, 19.10, desktop-environments, raspberrypi, cinnamon

Downloaded and flashed, Ubuntu Server 19.10.1 , to a 32GB SD card. Installed xubuntu desktop.
Cloned that to a couple of other sd cards.
Installed Ubuntu Mate on one.
https://itsfoss.com/install-mate-desktop-ubuntu/
Runs with no problems.
Installed cinnamon desktop from
https://www.tecmint.com/install-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu/
using the Universe PPA
Rebooted after install. Selected cinnamon at login.
I get a warning that cinnamon is running in software rendering mode.
Log out and select Xfce session there are no problems.

System:
  Host: ubuntu Kernel: 5.3.0-1022-raspi2 armv7l bits: 32 compiler: gcc 
  v: 9.2.1 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.10 dm: LightDM 
  Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Graphics:
  Device-1: bcm2708-fb driver: bcm2708_fb v: kernel bus ID: N/A 
  chip ID: brcm:soc 
  Device-2: bcm2835-hdmi driver: N/A bus ID: N/A chip ID: brcm:soc 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting 
  resolution: 1280x1024~N/A 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0 128 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8 
  compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes

The Graphics  are the same for both desktops.

Is there a way to get the cinnamon desktop not to run in software rendering mode?